# Is it acceptable to have a list in a MySQL column? Are lists searchable by SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

If I have a column in a table which is `tags` for example, and in that column an entry can be tagged with various keywords. Is it acceptable for an entry to have a list in that column instead of a single value?

So for example if I was putting a question into my table and I wanted to tag it as "math" and "physics", would it be acceptable to put `math, physics` into the `tags` column? And would it then later be possible to write a query that would be something along the lines of:

```
SELECT * FROM questions WHERE tags CONTAINS 'physics'
```

I know that `CONTAINS` is not a SQL operator but is there something that does that functionality? Or would i need to pull all entries from the table and then one by one search their tags for physics?

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET (although we may end up telling you that normalization is the answer)

Comment: If you are thinking of having `math, physics` in one `tag` column, this will actually violate the 1NF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Never, never, never store multiple values in one column!

That is the 3rd rule of DB normalization.

Use another table to map the tags to the questions:

```
questions table
---------------
id
title
.....

tags table
----------
id
name


question_tags table
-------------------
question_id
tag_id
```

After that you can look for questions that have a specific tag like this

```
select q.*
from questions q
join question_tags qt on qt.question_id = q.id
join tags t on t.id = qt.tag_id
where t.name = 'physics'
```

Comment: Ok so create a table which simply stores questions and then create a system of tables that will allow for searching questions?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Create a `tags` table and a `questiontags` table.

Comment: I updated my answer with a query that selects questions containing a specific tag.

Answer (score -1):

Its not really 3rd normal form to have a column full of tags. Rather, you might consider having a tags table that relates to the questions table. Consider the following tables. This  sets up a many to many relationship between questions and tags.

```
Questions:
QuestionID|*

Tags:
TagID|TagText

QuestionTags:
QuestionID|TagID
```

Then if you wanted all the physics questions a query something like this:

```
Select * from questions where questionid in (select questionID from questionTags where tagid in (select tagid from tags where tagtext = 'physics'))
```

Answer (score -2):

As far as something like `CONTAINS` is concerned, you might be looking for the `LIKE` operator

```
SELECT * FROM questions WHERE tags LIKE '%physics%'
```

The `%` on each side act as wildcards, so it doesn't matter where in the string your search term is.

However, as mentioned by drew010, it is not efficient at all as it has to search through the entire table. If your table is large, this method will be very slow and is not recommended.

Comment: This cannot take advantage of indexes and will result in linear search of the entire table.  If OP has a large number of values in the database this is not efficient.